# google maps - circle not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a google map with a marker and a circle on it, the marker works fine but the circle isn't appearing.

I've stared at the code and compared to a bunch of similar stuff online but for the life of me I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Can anyone help me out?

```
function initialize() {
    var userLocation = "London";
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var circle;
    var styles = [
                  {
                    stylers: [
                      { hue: "#00ffe6" },
                      { saturation: -20 }
                    ]
                  }
                ];
    geocoder.geocode( {"address": userLocation}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            //alert (latLng);
            var mapOptions = {
              center: latLng,
              zoom: 6,
              styles: styles,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                draggable: true
            });
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: map,
                radius: 50000, //your radius in meters
                fillColor: "#000000",
                center: point
            });
            $("#ListingGeolocation").val(results[0].geometry.location);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(){  
                var position = marker.getPosition();  
                map.setCenter(position);  
                $("#ListingGeolocation").val(position.lat() + " ," + position.lng());
            }); 
        } else {
           alert("Geocode failed. Please edit your address (top of the page) and try again.");
        }
     });
 }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

EDIT

i tried sticking the latLng variable from the above code as my center, but it didn't work

```
var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
```

Comment: the center of your circle is not supposed to be point, it is supposed to be latlng, right?

Comment: I changed it to a latlan as suggested - see Edit of Qu - didn't work tho :(

Comment: That's strange [it works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/n6p54/1/)

Comment: You were right, I was using 'center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng)' because I was a bit confused about what jonahfree was telling me. THanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have set a position for the circle.

Perhaps try changing `center: point` to `center: new google.maps.LatLng(YOURLAT, YOUR LONG)` as a test.